# Variable Assignments in BASH

Tags: bash

Reworded for better understanding.

I am customizing a git flow based plugin and I am trying to get the tail end of init to create a repo. I know all the commands to do it manually but for so reason I can't automate it.

```
REPO_NAME= `${PWD##*/}`
    echo $REPO_NAME
    ORG=':org_name'
    curl -u 'user:pass' \
      -d '{ "name": "'$REPO_NAME'",  "private": "true", "has_issues": "true", "has_wiki": "false", "has_downloads": "true"}' -i "https://api.github.com/orgs/$ORG/repos"
```

And no matter what I do to the command I always get this and curl fail.

```
/usr/local/bin/git-hf: 1: /usr/local/bin/git-hf: test-testy: not found

errors": [
{
  "code": "custom",
  "field": "name",
  "resource": "Repository",
  "message": "name is too short (minimum is 1 characters)"
}
```

],
  "message": "Validation Failed"

I know this is probably a stupid question but I am more concerned with the error in my logic here rather than the immediate solution.

Comment: Altered the question to better reflect what I am up to. I hope that helps. As I said above there is some issue with the way I want to assign that variable rather than the specific fix that I want to route out.

Answer (score 1):

Just try doing this :

```
dir=${PWD##*/}
echo "$dir"
```

Comment: sigh. So it was just the spacing. Thank You So Much. I really hate wasting peoples time.